# External table of an external table

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm trying a solution as follows:

1. Data lake has raw data file
2. Serverless Pool Synapse DB has external table to lake - working fine.
3. Azure PaaS SQL DB has external table which references Synapse pool external table.

I get an error message as follows:

> Login failed on
> ondemandserver.database.
> Please verify that the shards are accessible and that the credential
> information affiliated with external data source XXXX is
> correct

I'm trying to use a service account for the credentials on the PaaS database.  If we imagine the service account to be 'user@abc.com' and is in the same domain as the synapse workspace then the credential is setup as follows

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [synapse]
WITH
  IDENTITY = 'user' , -- intentionally no domain name as per microsft docs, adding domain generates a cannot open server error
  SECRET = 'pwd'
```

I have checked via storage explorer that user@abc.com has access.  I have logged on to the serverless pool using the service account credentials using SSMS successfully. I set up the external table on the serverless pool using the script generated in Synapse Studio.

I think there is some kind of issue with credential pass-through here, or a limitation around nesting external tables.

Using the sql admin credentials for the serverless pool generates a 'cannot locate file' error, which makes sense as I'm presumably trying to access the data lake using a sql authentication method.

If I can get over the login hurdle from the PaaS DB to Synapse I think this would resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [firewall configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure), when you create a new server in Azure SQL Database or Azure Synapse Analytics named mysqlserver, for example, a server-level firewall blocks all access to the public endpoint for the server (which is accessible at mysqlserver.database.windows.net).

Azure Synapse only supports server-level IP firewall rules. It doesn't support database-level IP firewall rules

[How the firewall works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#how-the-firewall-works)  By default, during creation of a new logical SQL server from the Azure portal, the Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server setting is set to No. [Connections from inside Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#connections-from-inside-azure)

Below errors seem to be related:

[Error 26](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues#error-26-error-locating-server-specified): Error Locating server specified: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 – Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

[Error 40](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues#error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-the-server): Could not open a connection to the server: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Also, elastic database query is supported on the Premium service tier of SQL DB as the query endpoint, while the collection of databases involved in queries may be any tier. (This Premium restriction is temporary for the early stages of Preview.)

[To confirm whether an error is caused by a connectivity issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues#confirm-whether-an-error-is-caused-by-a-connectivity-issue), review the stack trace for frames that show calls to open a connection like the following ones (note the reference to the SqlConnection class)

For [Database-scoped master key and credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started#database-scoped-master-key-and-credentials), it creates a database credential. A database credential is not mapped to a server login or database user. The credential is used by the database to access to the external location anytime the database is performing an operation that requires access.

[Synatx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax):

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credential_name
WITH IDENTITY = 'identity_name'
    [ , SECRET = 'secret' ]
```

credential_name Specifies the name of the database scoped credential being created. credential_name cannot start with the number (#) sign. System credentials start with ##.

IDENTITY ='identity_name' Specifies the name of the account to be used when connecting outside the server. To import a file from Azure Blob storage using a shared key, the identity name must be SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE. To load data into Azure Synapse Analytics, any valid value can be used for identity.

When using Kerberos (Windows Active Directory or MIT KDC) do not use the domain name in the IDENTITY argument. It should just be the account name.

SQL Database uses database scoped credentials for its global query feature

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I've discussed this on Microsoft Q&A and the general consensus is that elastic queries do not support AD - hence the error.  Therefore, you have to use sql auth and it looks as through that is being passed through to the nested external data source and causes an auth error trying to connect to the lake (because it is using the sql auth from the elastic query and not the AD auth on the nested external data source) - am awaiting confirmation.

Comment: Oh, great, keep us posted ✌

Comment: Will do, looks like I will have to deploy to the serverless pool instead of the PaaS for prod in this case, which is a bit of rearchitecture work :(